# How to import functions from another file in NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, joi

I'm new in NodeJS, and I'm struggling a little bit on this. I'm using **Express** and to validate the data, I'm using **[Celebrate](https://github.com/arb/celebrate)**.

I've got a **route.js** file, where I make a **POST** request, using a function from another file to do so (it's the **create** function, from **MyController**. It works fine! But when I try to do the same thing to my *validator*, it doesn't work.

So let's take a look at the code.

The **route.js** file:

```js
const express = require("express");

const MyController = require("./controllers/MyController");
const MyValidator= require("./validators/MyValidator");

const routes = express.Router();

routes.post("/path", MuValidator.validateCreate, MyController.create);
```

The **MyValidator** file:

```js
module.exports = {

  validateCreate() {
    celebrate({
      [Segments.HEADERS]: Joi.object({
        authorization: Joi.string().required(),
      }).unknown(),
      [Segments.BODY]: Joi.object().keys({
        userId: Joi.string().required(),
        title: Joi.string().required(),
        description: Joi.string().required(),
        value: Joi.number().required(),
        dueDate: Joi.string().required(),
      }),
    });
  },
}
```

**IMPORTANT**: 
I only get this working, if I write the *validation code* directly on my route, like this:

```js
routes.post(
  "/path",
  celebrate({
    [Segments.HEADERS]: Joi.object({
      authorization: Joi.string().required(),
    }).unknown(),
    [Segments.BODY]: Joi.object().keys({
      userId: Joi.string().required(),
      title: Joi.string().required(),
      description: Joi.string().required(),
      value: Joi.number().required(),
      dueDate: Joi.string().required(),
    }),
  }),
  MyController.create
);
```

Comment: Define _it doesn't work_

Comment: @AyushGupta, but is it something I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem is that the *celebrate* function creates and returns a middleware, so the middleware returned by the celebrate function must be passed as second parameter to the post but you're passing **a function that execute the celebrate method** instead, so validateCreate should be:

```js
module.exports = {
    validateCreate: celebrate({...})
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you did something wrong with module exports

try something like this:

```
module.exports = {
    validateCreate: function() {},
    otherMethod: function() {},
};
```